# Where can I found the api key and secret key will be available for firebase crachlytics

Tags: android, ios, firebase, crashlytics, fastlane

Where can I found the api key and secret key will be available for firebase crachlytics.

I am setting the fastlane setup to upload the build to firebase and need to enable crashlytics.

Answer (score 0):

Those keys are in your google services file.

Edit: For Firebase, please refer to this documentation https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution#-firebase-app-distribution

Comment: I can found the"api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyBjdfhjfjdhfwuiefwjefweijfewifuhwiefweifbwiefbwiefbewf'
        }
      ], not able to found app secret

Comment: How can I increase the build number for android using fastlane in firebase(for ios and android) manual and automatically

Comment: That is because you are looking at the Fabric section. I will edit my post with updated information.